# Django checking an object's attribute's value

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have two similar models that have type attributes that equals "taxi" or "bus" and I want to check if an object is taxi or bus in my context processor.
I tried

```
if element.type == "bus":
```

but it returned none. This is because it's not that straight forward, I know. I also tried to transform the `element.type` to `str`, it showed the problem but I don't know how to fix.

models.py:

```
class Element(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

user only can add "taxi" or "bus" as strings to type field.

views:

```
def home(request, id):
    site = Site.objects.get(id=id)
    elements = Element.objects.filter(site_name=site)

    return render_to_response("base.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

base.html:

```
{% load ttag %}
{% for e in elements %}
{% elements request e.id %}
{% endfor %}
```

context processor:

```
def elements(request, id):
    element = Element.objects.get(id=id)
    if element.type == "taxi":
        list = {'element':element}
        return render_to_string("taxi.html", list)
    elif element.type == "bus":
        list = {'element':element}
        return render_to_string("bus.html", list)
```

How can I check whether it's a bus or taxi?
Thanks.

Comment: Please, provide your model and view code.

Comment: Added model and view.

Comment: Can you show exactly what error you're getting? This comparison should work, assuming that the particular `element` that you're looking for exists..

Comment: did you mean to have "render to response" for bus and "render_to_string" for taxi?

Comment: can i see your "urls.py" as well? Also, what's in "bus.html" and "taxi.html"

Comment: I updated the question. It just says none instead of template tag in base.html.

Comment: I need to see "taxi".html and "base.html"  are they both inheriting from base?  If not, base.html isn't going to print out anything...

Comment: they are not inheriting, also I don't think they don't need to inherited. They only has `{{ element.type }}` in them for now. But it shows `None` in main url, on `base.html`.

Comment: normally, you have a base template that child templates extend...for example you'd have a base.html that has all common elements among taxi and bus....bus.html and taxi.html then deal with the different elements.  also, your urls.py would be relevant here as well.

Comment: I know that, but I use custom template tag in here. In this case I don't need to extend any other template to them. Also I just want to check the attribute. I don't get any error, it just returns None. This shouldn't be relevant to extending templates.

Comment: where are "taxi.html" and "bus.html" coming from...?  also, what you are referring to as a "templatetag" is a view, not a template tag (it has the request object...)

Comment: I'm not a pro and I used this solve in other projects to. It's working fine, it puts an external html code to base.html without problem normally. But when I check them, it's not returning anything. Again, it's not relevant with templates. Just need to know how to check a attribute equals a string or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think it probably *is* that straightforward and I sense that you're working a lot harder than you need to. This should work:

In view code:

```
elements = Element.objects.filter(site_name=site)  # or whatever
```

In template code:

```
{% for e in elements %}
    {% if e.type == 'taxi' %}
       <!-- do taxi stuff -->
    {% elif e.type == 'bus' %}
       <!-- do bus stuff -->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If that doesn't do the trick, what's going wrong? Are you certain that all "element" objects have a "type" attribute?

Comment: this is working fine but I need to do it on context processor. This won't be useful for future of project. I need do get things done in context processor so in py file. Any idea to do that?

Comment: From what I've see here, I would avoid that approach, frankly. If what you want to do is conditionally render another template, there are far easier ways to do that.

Comment: I should exactly do it in context processor. Is there any way to do?

Comment: @paradoksumsu Fair enough. I've only had experience solving this type of problem by a different approach, so I'm afraid I can't help much under your assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you got the idea to use a context processor, but that can't be used as a function within a template. A context processor changes the context within a template *before* you start to render the template.

An easy solution would be to add a method to `Element` and include the template dynamically:

```
class Element(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def get_template_name(self):
        if self.type == "bus":
            return 'bus.html'
        if self.type == "taxi":
            return 'taxi.html'
```

In your template:

```
{% for element in elements %}
    {% include element.get_template_name with element=element %}
{% endfor %}
```